# What is the power of a laser welding machine that can penetrate a weld of 10mm stainless steel?

Tags: welding, lasers

Can a laser welding machine penetrate a weld of 10mm stainless steel?

Comment: The answer to any such question is in most cases "yes". but it's not a question that's related to EE.

Answer (score 1):

This [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0261306913006006) from Hunan University in Changsha illustrates 12mm penetration welding of stainless steel using a 10kW fiber laser and shielding gas supplied both sides.

[image]

There are also references to other papers, generally with higher powers available. I didn't look at them. In any case, it appears 10kW should be sufficient for 10mm SS.